# Exception in renaming file name in ADLS Gen2 through PowerShell

Tags: azure, rest, powershell, azure-data-lake

I’m able to create files and folders in ADLS using PowerShell and ADLS Gen 2 REST API. However I’m having trouble renaming the file. I am using “x-ms-rename-source” in the header but its throwing exception.

code:

```
$n = '`n'
$stringToSign +=
#SECTION: CanonicalizedHeaders + “\n” #
“x-ms-date:$date” + $n +
“x-ms-version:2018-11-09” + $n +
“x-ms-rename-source:/adlsg2filesystemname/folderpath/filename” + $n
$stringToSign +=
# SECTION: CanonicalizedResource + “\n” #
“/$StorageAccountName/$FilesystemName” + $PathToCreate + $n

$sharedKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($AccessKey)
$hasher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hasher.Key = $sharedKey

$signedSignature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hasher.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign)))

$authHeader = “SharedKey ${StorageAccountName}:$signedSignature”

$headers = @{“x-ms-date”=$date}
$headers.Add(“x-ms-version”,”2018-11-09″)
$headers.Add(“x-ms-rename-source”,”/adlsg2filesystemname/folderpath/filename”)
$headers.Add(“Authorization”,$authHeader)
$headers.Add(“If-None-Match”,”*”) # To fail if the destination already exists, use a conditional request with If-None-Match: “*”

$URI = “https://$StorageAccountName.dfs.core.windows.net/” + $FilesystemName + $PathToCreate
```

I am getting below exception:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly 
including the signature.\nRequestId:ddfd851b-501f-0057-3f88-7e0a7d000000\nTime:2019-10-09T09:59:53.7708781Z"}}
```

Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @kabhu Do you have any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, we can use Azure AD authentication to call Azure data lake storage Gen2 REST API. For more details, please refer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45be0931-379d-4252-9d20-164261cc64c5/error-while-calling-adls-gen-2-rest-api-to-create-file?forum=AzureDataLake.

1. Create Azure AD service principal and assign a RABC role to it. For further information, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$password=''
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential -Property @{ StartDate=Get-Date; EndDate=Get-Date -Year 2024; Password=$password}
$sp = New-AzAdServicePrincipal -DisplayName jimtest1 -PasswordCredential $credentials

New-AzRoleAssignment -ApplicationId $sp.ApplicationId -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Blob Data Owner" -Scope "your scope such as your storage account scope"
```

2. get access token

```
$TeantID='hanxia.onmicrosoft.com'
$TokenResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TeantID)/oauth2/token" -Body @{
    client_id     = $sp.ApplicationId # the application id of service principal
    resource = 'https://storage.azure.com'
    grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
    client_secret = $password # you use it in step 1

}
```

3. Call the rest api

```
$StorageAccountName =''
$FilesystemName =''
$PathToCreate=''
$URI = “https://$StorageAccountName.dfs.core.windows.net/” + $FilesystemName +"/"+$PathToCreate
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $URI   -Headers @{
'Authorization' = "Bearer "+ $TokenResult.access_token
'x-ms-rename-source' = ' '
}
```

[image]
[image]